# How to put different layouts for child items in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, get-childitem

I develop an Android App, so I'm trying to use the `ExpandableListView` to use two different layouts for each child. But I have a problem and can't seem to fix it. I thought the problem was that I didn't get the right child. Both children display the two layouts at the same time.

This my **class Adapter** !

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;
public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups) {
this.context = context;
this.groups = groups;
}

public void addItem(ExpandListChild item, ExpandListGroup group) {
if (!groups.contains(group)) {
groups.add(group);
}
int index = groups.indexOf(group);
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> ch = groups.get(index).getItems();
ch.add(item);
groups.get(index).setItems(ch);
}
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
return chList.get(childPosition);
}
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
return 2;
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
//return childPosition;
return (long)( groupPosition*50+childPosition );
}
@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
int result = 0;
if (childPosition == getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)
result = 1;

return result;
}


public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
ViewGroup parent) {
TextView textView = null;
ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
/*  if (view == null) {
if(childPosition == 0){
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);}
else if (childPosition == 1){
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child2, null);

}
}*/

if (view == null) {
int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);

if(itemType == 0)
{


view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
textView.setText("0");
//textView.setTag(child.getTag());
}
else
{ view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child2, null);
textView  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild1);
textView.setText("1");
textView.setTag(child.getTag());}
/*
switch (itemType) {
case 0:
{    view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
textView.setText("0");
//textView.setTag(child.getTag());
break;}
case 1:
{   view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child2, null);
textView  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild1);
textView.setText("1");
textView.setTag(child.getTag());
break;}
}
*/

//textView.setPadding(30,20,30,20);


}

//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return view;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();

return chList.size();

}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return groups.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
ViewGroup parent) {
ExpandListGroup group = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
if (view == null) {
LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
}
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
tv.setText(group.getName());
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return view;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
return true;
}
```

The **child2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChild1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="17sp" >
  </TextView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkboxh" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**expandablelist_child_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:background="@color/ExpandChildBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="17sp" >
   </TextView>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below you can see the run of the first and second child.

[image]

[image]

Comment: similar problem I'm facing..any luck here?

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0;
if (childPosition == getChildrenCount(groupPosition)-1)//logical fail ?
result = 1;
```

try to return "child_pos"

getChildrenCount will give u everey time the same value. u have 2 childs -1 = 1

btw. check this initialisation

```
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are executing the following code snippet only in case where view is null which is wrong and should do that irrespective of whether view is null / not null.

```
if(itemType == 0)
{

view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
textView.setText("0");
//textView.setTag(child.getTag());
}
else
{ view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child2, null);
textView  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild1);
textView.setText("1");
}
```

Comment: Then you're inflating every single time and your performance will be very bad